# Enabling Compression on Avro via PySpark

Tags: compression, pyspark, avro, snappy, spark-avro

Using PySpark I'm trying to save an Avro file with compression (preferably snappy).

This line of code successfully saves a 264MB file:

`df.write.mode('overwrite').format('com.databricks.spark.avro').save('s3n://%s:%s@%s/%s' % (access_key, secret_key, aws_bucket_name, output_file))`

When I add the codec option `.option('codec', 'snappy')` the code successfully runs but the file size is still 264MB:

`df.write.mode('overwrite').option('codec', 'snappy').format('com.databricks.spark.avro').save('s3n://%s:%s@%s/%s' % (access_key, secret_key, aws_bucket_name, output_file))`

I've also tried `'SNAPPY'` and `'Snappy'` and it also runs successfully but with the same file size.

I've [read the documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) but it focuses on Java and Scala. Is this not supported in PySpark, is Snappy the default and it's not documented, or am I not using the correct syntax? There's also [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071481/set-avro-compression-in-hive-from-pyspark) (I assume) but it's focused on Hive and has no answers.

TIA

Comment: The documentation is also there https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-avro.html (exactly the same but with a nicer display) and it's quite explicit: **AVRO does not support the `.option()` syntax at DataFrame level, you must set a global Spark property.**

Comment: Also, the source code here https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-3.2/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/DefaultSource.scala shows that AVRO supports only "snappy" and "deflate" codecs. And **the default is "snappy"** so why do you care???

Comment: If you really can't guess how to change the Spark conf in Python, then look at that example: http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/83823/pyspark.SparkConf *(note that the `SparkConf` object appears to be a clone, you cannot just update it, you have to re-create the `SparkContext` to enforce the new properties)*

Answer (score 0):

I believe by default, spark is enabled with Snappy compression. you try to compare the size with uncompressed format, you should see the size difference.